# cabal build for my project fails linking llvm-general package

Tags: haskell, cabal, build-error

I have a cabal project, when I issue `cabal build` I get this :

```
Building phjava-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'phjava' for phjava-0.1.0.0...
[2 of 3] Compiling CodeGen          ( src/CodeGen.hs, dist/build/phjava/phjava-tmp/CodeGen.o )

<no location info>: error:
    <command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for: /usr/lib/libcurses.so (-lncursesw: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

This is the output with `--verbose=3` : [verbose output](http://pastebin.com/J7rgGDnL)

This is my cabal file :

```
name:                 phjava
version:              0.1.0.0
synopsis:
-- description:
-- license:
-- license-file:
homepage:
author:               abnud1
maintainer:           ahmad13932013@hotmail.com
category:             Language
-- copyright:
build-type:           Simple
-- extra-source-files:
cabal-version:        >=1.10

executable phjava
  main-is:              Main.hs
  -- other-modules:
  -- other-extensions:
  build-depends:        base >= 4.7 && < 5 , parsec < 4, containers < 1 , regex-pcre < 1 , parsec-permutation < 1 , transformers < 1 , logfloat < 0.14, llvm-general-pure < 4, llvm-general, mtl < 3
  hs-source-dirs:       src
  default-language:     Haskell2010
  ghc-options: -Wall
```

I have ghc 8.0.1, cabal 1.24, llvm-3.8.1 . I installed llvm-general by cloning the llvm-3.8 branch and running cabal install with -fshared-llvm.

I assure you I have ncurses installed, also `libcurses.so` file is a symlink to `/usr/lib/libncurses.so`, I also have `/usr/lib/libncursesw.so` (which is also a symlink to `/usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6`).

Last my OS is Arch Linux 64 bit and I also have ncurses5-compat-libs installed from AUR(and uninstalling it didn't help).

Comment: See https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9237.

Comment: @ReidBarton hmmm I saw something like that but I hoped I wouldn't have to change a system-wide file like that but if it is a bug then that's the best solution I guess